# How do I control where pip3 installs packages?

Tags: python, pip

I updated pip3 and now packages are being installed for python 3.8 and not 3.9. What do I do to make it so that packages are installed to where they used to be installed?

I updated pip3 today using the command `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and then installed a new package with `pip3 install statsmodels` which did indeed install the package. I checked the install location with `pip3 list -v` and saw that the package and its dependencies were installed to /Users/myusername/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages.

The problem is... this is not where my other packages are. `pip3 list -v` doesn't show any of the packages I've installed in the past (for example, I know I have matplotlib installed but it doesn't show up). I only use python 3.9, so I don't want any of my packages being installed for python 3.8 but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: If you use that packages on daily basis in multiple projects - try to figure out why pip of python 3.8 is earlier in path compared to pip of 3.9 and fix that. What does `python` resolve to? If `python -V` prints 3.9.x, then you can just do `python -m pip install ...`, otherwise `python3.9 -m pip install ...` should work. However, if you never use python 3.8, then you'd better remove it completely or at least do not let it appear in PATH. If you use different packages for different projects, consider using virtual environments instead. Also, could you try `pip` instead of `pip3`?

Comment: `python -V` doesn't return anything. `python3 -V` returns Python 3.8.9... so you're saying If I do `python3.9 -m pip3 install  ...` that would work?

Comment: Aha, then you have your path changed for some reason ("doesn't return anything" is quite interesting and almost impossible, though). You can try to configure PATH so that folder with 3.8 goes after 3.9 and make that changes persistent (or just purge 3.8 from your system, 3.9 is stable enough to work as system python) or make a habit to use `python3.9` always and call pip as `python3.9 -m pip ...`

Comment: Okay, I think I'll try to configure the PATH like you said so that i don't have this problem in the future. I just did `python3.9 -m pip install statsmodels` and that did what I wanted it to do, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your default installation target

The [--target](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) switch is the thing you're looking for:

```
pip config set global.target /Users/Bob/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages
```

Installs packages into directory provied. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in the directory. Use [--upgrade](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-U) to replace existing packages in  with new versions.

Comment: Although this directly answers the question, it probably isn't what the OP should be doing. This would have the pip global target directory set for *another* interpreter's site-directory. I'm pretty sure this would strangely lead to `/path/to/specific/python -m pip install <whatever>` to potentially not install to the `/path/to/specific/python` site packages, which would be very strange.

Comment: The OP *should* make sure they know which `pip` is being resolved in the PATH ideally by using virtual environments or by using the `python -m pip` form at the very least